# How can I make multi-value query?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, mariadb

I use Maria DB.I have a table of statistics where operations with water are counted. I have three types of water 0,2,3. But there is water type 0, which includes type 2, type 3 and type 0, that is, water type 0 = 0 + 2 + 3.How do I sample for water type 0, it should be something like this 0 = 0-2-3.I have a period marker, when the period is 1, I keep count.I write query and it works,but i need to use a few `statistical_id` I try to use functions `IN` and  get result only with minimum value (3133) , why?

```
id  statistical_id  period  water water_type    created_at
29229825    3133    1   37.50   0   2020-10-26 22:00:00
29229827    3133    1   30.00   3   2020-10-26 22:00:00
29228803    3144    1   57.50   0   2020-10-26 22:00:00
29238998    3133    1   1.50    2   2020-10-26 22:00:00
29228811    3144    1   51.50   3   2020-10-26 22:00:00
29228807    3144    1   2.50    2   2020-10-26 22:00:00
29222427    3145    1   0.00    0   2020-10-25 22:00:00
29214408    3144    1   2.50    2   2020-10-25 22:00:00
29214183    3144    1   56.50   3   2020-10-25 22:00:00
29214179    3144    1   62.50   0   2020-10-25 22:00:00
29214971    3133    1   31.50   0   2020-10-25 22:00:00
29215195    3133    1   3.00    2   2020-10-25 22:00:00
29214974    3133    1   20.00   3   2020-10-25 22:00:00
29199695    3144    1   122.00  0   2020-10-24 21:00:00
29200438    3133    1   20.00   0   2020-10-24 21:00:00
```

and result

```
device_id water_type `date` water
    3133    0   2020-10-25  8.5
    3133    0   2020-10-26  6
```

query

```
select statistical_id device_id, water_type, date(CONVERT_TZ (created_at,'+00:00','+02:00')) date,
sum(case when water_type = 0 then water
                    else - water
               end) water
    from `production`.statistics 
    where statistical_id in (3144, 3133, 3145)
          and created_at >= '2020-10-04 22:00:00'
          and created_at <= '2020-10-15 22:00:00'
          and period = 1
          and water_type in (0, 2, 3)
          group by date(created_at);
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: What's your logic and expected result?

Comment: I correct question, can you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `group by statistical_id, date` and aggregate:

```
select statistical_id, 
       date(created_at) date,
       sum(case when water_type = 0 then water else - water end) water
from statistics 
where statistical_id in (3144, 3133, 3145)
  and created_at >= '2020-10-04 22:00:00' and created_at <= '2020-10-15 22:00:00'
  and period = 1
  and water_type in (0, 2, 3)
group by statistical_id, date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2017ab6db0b218a2743bbfd664899463).
Results (for your sample data without the date conditions):

```
> statistical_id | date       | water
> -------------: | :--------- | ----:
>           3133 | 2020-10-24 |    20
>           3133 | 2020-10-25 |   8.5
>           3133 | 2020-10-26 |     6
>           3144 | 2020-10-24 |   122
>           3144 | 2020-10-25 |   3.5
>           3144 | 2020-10-26 |   3.5
>           3145 | 2020-10-25 |     0
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Do you simply want aggregation?

```
select statistical_id,
       sum(case when water_type = 0 then water
                else - water
           end)
from `production`.statistics 
where statistical_id in (3144, 3133, 3145) and
      created_at >= '2020-10-04 21:00:00' and
      created_at <= '2020-10-15 21:00:00' and
      period = 1 and
      water_type in (0, 2, 3)
group by statistical_id
```